# Testing app on iOS deviced with Windows

Tags: ios, testing, provisioning

I'm trying to distribute my app to beta testers. One of those testers has a pc. Now I've noticed that the instructions in here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/YourFirstAppStoreSubmission/TestYourApponManyDevicesandiOSVersions/TestYourApponManyDevicesandiOSVersions.html
under To install the app on a device . . . refer to Macs.
My tester tried to do the same on his pc (opening the mobileprov file, dragging ipa to itunes and syncing, but he got an unspecific error, saying "~My App Name~ couldn't install on this device".

Is there a **method of doing the procedure on *Windows* and managing to get the app up and running on the iDevice?**, although not mentioned on the site?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

For beta tests I recommend [Testflight](https://testflightapp.com/) or the use of [Beta Builder](http://www.hanchorllc.com/betabuilder-for-ios/), you can upload to your dropbox and mail the link to your testers. Testers open the link on their phone and install the app from the phone, no need to use itunes.

The benefit of Testflight is that you get symbolicated crash reports and you see how many hours your app is tested. It's free and uncomplicated.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

There is also ad hoc distribution too, [here's](https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/distribute.html) a link that talks about it, but really not much else.